# What could cause an intermittent "Class not Registered" (0x80040154) error on a third party dll?

Tags: c++, dll, com, mfc

My 32-bit MFC C++ (VS 2010) application uses a 32-bit dll COM component that is registered by our installer with the vsdrfCOM option.  The application runs on Windows 7 Pro 64-bit.

We are getting a new error that is intermittent on only one system that is based on the same drive image as several other systems that have never seen this error.  We are calling this code several times a second.  Looks like there is room to make more efficient, but why never any problems before?

```
// Initialize SPC I/O Library COM object
(void)CoInitialize(NULL); // Initialize COM
CComPtr<IGSpcIO> pSpcIO; // define COM pointer to the SPC I/O Library object
HRESULT hr = pSpcIO.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_GSpcIO); // Create COM pointer
```

The code above works most of the time but I'm getting an intermittent failure on the CoCreateInstance() call.

What other issues should I be looking for that might be returning 0x80040154?

Comment: That is *never* an intermittent error.  Junk the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why it would be intermittent.  I would use procmon.exe to look at registry access and file access to see what the conditions are when it fails.  You need to know whether it cannot find the class in the registry or whether it is having problems loading the DLL (COM server).